# setting specific 'window' constraints into a word document for images

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010

I want to enable users to simply drop any image they want into a template in Word and not require them to crop or re-size anything. If the image is larger, those areas that fall outside of my pre-defined "canvas" do not appear, but the user can move the image around to centre in within that canvas.

Can this layering be completed in Word 2010?

Comment: You can draw a text box and drag and drop an image into it. The image will automatically scale to the box, but it won't crop the image. The down side is that when you delete the image the text box reverts to the smallest possible dimensions.